# Create a cheque with Xero API

Tags: xero-api

I am new to developing with [Xero](https://developer.xero.com/). I have a requirement to create and issue a cheque to a party. From this [link](https://help.xero.com/int/CheckStyleAdd), it seems that Xero does support the cheque's creation. I could not however find the developer documentation which can enable me to do the same using REST API calls. Is this at all possible? Am I missing something?

Your help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not currently to access or create checks through our API service. As such this process would need to be completed through the web interface on a manual basis.

Our UserVoice page has a request for this: https://xero.uservoice.com/forums/5528-xero-accounting-api/suggestions/32389996-access-checks-via-api-call

Comment: Thanks RobinXero for your answer.